# rails API gets timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, timeout

I have rails API that is not using `ActiveResource::Base` class for model. The problem is my API calls another rails app for storing data to oracle DB. This process takes longer time and hence my API gets timeout but still the process on another rails app is ruuning. I can't use `self.timeout` method of `ActiveResource::Base` to extend the timelimit of my API. Can anyone suggest how to fix this issue ?

EDIT

```
class MyResources::MyModel
  include MyResource
  include ActiveModel::Serialization

  attribute :id
  attribute :name
end
```

This is my model. I am not inheriting from `ActiveResource::Base`. MyResouce is my custom library.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

1. **Offload work to a background process**. If your app is doing heavy processing while serving a request you might want to pass that work to a process that doesn't block the request itself. Try [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq), for example.
2. **Set a timeout on the call to the other rails app**. Most http libraries support this.

Comment: Since I am not using `ActiveResource::Base` so I don't have the method `timeout`. It will be great if you can name other libraries that have the same functionality.

Comment: edited the question with example of my model. The first option of Off loading is not working since we can't have success status (HTTP status code i.e.200 ) after completing process.